# How do I make a maze tile 3x3

Tags: c++

Like the question says, I have a 10X11 array and I need each tile to be a 3x3 instead of 1x1 and Im not sure how to do that. I also am having trouble pulling the correct x value for my finish point. Any help would be much appreciated. here is my code so far:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <fstream>

#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    //establishing constant variables;
    const char Walls = '#';
    const char Mazes = '-';
    const int row = 10;
    const int col = 11;

    //defining strings to pull from text file
    std::string arraysize_sx;
    std::string arraysize_sy;
    std::string start_sx;
    std::string start_sy;
    std::string finish_sx;
    std::string finish_sy;
    std::string walls_s;

    std::ifstream openfile ("input.txt");
    std::ofstream outputfile ("output.txt",std::ios::app);

    //gets points from text file, using , and . as delimiters
    std::getline(openfile, arraysize_sx , ',');
    std::getline(openfile, arraysize_sy, '.');
    std::getline(openfile, start_sx, ',');
    std::getline(openfile, start_sy, '.');
    std::getline(openfile, finish_sx , ',');
    std::getline(openfile, finish_sy , '.');
    std::getline(openfile,walls_s, '.');


    int startx,starty;
    int finishx,finishy;

    //convert string to int
    std::stringstream rowconv(arraysize_sx);
    std::stringstream colconv(arraysize_sy);
    std::stringstream startsx(start_sx);
    std::stringstream startsy(start_sy);
    std::stringstream finishsx(finish_sx);
    std::stringstream finishsy(finish_sy);


//    rowconv >> row;
//    colconv >> col;
    startsx >> startx;
    startsy >> starty;
    finishsx >> finishx;
    finishsy >> finishy;

    //defining the shape of the maze
    char maze [col][row] = {
        {'-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-'},
        {'-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-'},
        {'-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-'},
        {'-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-'},
        {'-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-'},
        {'-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-'},
        {'-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-'},
        {'-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-'},
        {'-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-'},
        {'-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-'},
        {'-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-'},
    };

    maze[startx][starty] = 's';
    maze[finishx+3][finishy] = 'f';
    outputfile << *maze;





    openfile.close();
}
```

Here is my .txt input for refrence, each different point is marked by a period. i.e dimentions. start. finish. walls:

```
10, 11.
(0, 0).
(3, 10).
(0, 6), (0, 7), (0, 9), 
(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 4), (1, 7),
(2, 1), (2, 7), (2, 8), (2, 10),
(3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3), (3, 4), (3, 7),
(4, 0), (4, 6), (4, 9), (4, 10),
(5, 2), (5, 3), (5, 4), (5, 5), (5, 7),
(6, 1), (6, 8), (6, 9),
(7, 1), (7, 2), (7, 3), (7, 6), 
(8, 1), (8, 5), (8, 6), (8, 8), (8, 10),
(9, 3), (9, 7).
```

Update:

I updated my code so that instead of creating the array like I did above. I used for loops to create the start and finish. Im still working on adding the walls in and creating 3X3 squares for each point. I'm trying to find out if its possible to place a 3X3 array within one point on another array.

Updated code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>


int main()
{
    //establishing constant variables;
    const int row = 10;
    const int col = 11;
    double p1x,p1y;

    //defining strings to pull from text file
    std::string arraysize_sx;
    std::string arraysize_sy;
    std::string start_sx;
    std::string start_sy;
    std::string finish_sx;
    std::string finish_sy;
//    std::string walls_sx;
//    std::string walls_sy;
    std::string walls_sf;

    std::ifstream openfile ("input.txt");
    std::ofstream outputfile ("output.txt",std::ios::app);

//    int wx,wy;
    int startx,starty;
    int finishx,finishy;
    //gets points from text file, using , and . as delimiters
    std::getline(openfile, arraysize_sx , ',');
    std::getline(openfile, arraysize_sy, '.');
    std::getline(openfile, start_sx, ',');
    std::getline(openfile, start_sy, '.');
    std::getline(openfile, finish_sx , ',');
    std::getline(openfile, finish_sy , '.');
//        std::getline(openfile,walls_sx, ',');
//        std::getline(openfile,walls_sy, ',');
    std::getline(openfile,walls_sf, '.');

        //convert string to int
    std::stringstream rowconv(arraysize_sx);
    std::stringstream colconv(arraysize_sy);
    std::stringstream startsx(start_sx);
    std::stringstream startsy(start_sy);
    std::stringstream finishsx(finish_sx);
    std::stringstream finishsy(finish_sy);
//        std::stringstream wallx(walls_sx);
//        std::stringstream wally(walls_sy);

    startsx >> startx;
    startsy >> starty;
    finishsx >> finishx;
    finishsy >> finishy;
//        wallx >> wx;
//        wally >> wy;



    //defining the shape of the maze
    char maze [col][row];
    char s [3][3] = {
        {'-','-','-'},
        {'-','S','-'},
        {'-','-','-'}
    };

    //defining the start point and endpoint using the points pulled from the text file
    for (int x = 0; x < col; x++){
        for (int y = 0; y < row; y++){
            if (x == startx && y == starty){
                maze[x][y] = 'S';
            }
            else if (y == finishx+3 && x == finishy){
                maze[x][y] = 'F';
            }
            else{
                maze [x][y] = '-';
            }
        }
    }

    std::cout << walls_sf << std::endl;
```

Comment: How should one of the 3x3 tiles look like? The character from the arrays in the middle and 8 times ` ` around it?

Comment: Are you aware of the syntax, use and behaviour of loops? E.g. the `for(...;...;...)` loop.

Comment: Why do you conversion functions return string instead of int?

Comment: May I recommend this helpful article, which describes a great method for practically any programming problem?
 https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/21/find-a-simpler-problem/

Comment: What does your output look like (show it)? Can you describe your output? Can you describe the output you want? Can you describe the difference, using terms like "missing newline", "unwanted newline", "missing space", "unwanted space"?

Comment: Can you describe what this line does? `std::stringstream rowconv(arraysize_sx);` Especially discuss the position of this line (and similar lines) in the middle of the function `main()`, i.e. why are these lines not outside of a function?

Comment: each array point should look like this:
'-' '-' '-'
'-' 'S' '-'
'-' '-' '-'
that would represent start. finish would have an F and walls would be all # signs

Comment: Why is 10x11 array where every element is 3x3 array simpler to use for floor maze than 30x33 array?

Comment: @EthanMacanas Thanks for the answer to 1 of my 5 clarification questions. Did you notice the other 4?